# posting ObjectContent via HttpClient to TelegramApi reutns statusCode 400

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dotnet-httpclient, telegram-bot

I'm working on Telegram Bot to make it sync with our own application...
I first went to DHC chrome extension which is similar to RestClient extension, and test the way i should send and receive data from Telegram server. Second, i want to do it in C#, i already implement the getUpdate, which i receive incoming messages from Telegram. now i'm at outgoing stage, and i keep receiving StatusCode of 400...

Can anyone say why? and what to do?

Bot references can be found [in here...](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)

```
public class SendMessage<TReplyMarkup>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Integer Or String
    /// </summary>
    public string ChatId { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ParseMode { get; set; }
    public bool? DisableWebPagePreview { get; set; }
    public bool? DisableNotification { get; set; }
    public long? ReplyToMessageId { get; set; }
    public TReplyMarkup ReplyMarkup { get; set; }
}



public void Process(Update update)
{
    SendMessage<Object> newMessage = new SendMessage<object>();
    newMessage.Text = "Posting Message";
    newMessage.ChatId = update.Message.Chat.Id.ToString();

    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

    HttpContent requestContent = new ObjectContent(typeof(SendMessage<object>), newMessage, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CustomPropertyNamesContractResolver
            {
                Case = IdentifierCase.UnderscoreSeparator
            }
        },
    SupportedEncodings = { Encoding.UTF8 }
    });

    var responseMessage = hc.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + AppSetting.Token + "/sendMessage", requestContent).Result;
                //parse, see if is ok...    
}
```

Here my Object statuses:

The content that i want to send:

```
requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync()

Id = 77, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "{\"chat_id\":\"55815152\",\"text\":\"Posting Message\",\"parse_mode\":null,\"disable_web_page_preview\":null,\"disable_notification\":null,\"reply_to_message_id\":null,\"reply_markup\":null}"
    AsyncState: null
    CancellationPending: false
    CreationOptions: None
    Exception: null
    Id: 77
    Result: "{\"chat_id\":\"55815152\",\"text\":\"Posting Message\",\"parse_mode\":null,\"disable_web_page_preview\":null,\"disable_notification\":null,\"reply_to_message_id\":null,\"reply_markup\":null}"
    Status: RanToCompletion
```

The content that i receive:

```
responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Id = 80, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "{\"ok\":false,\"error_code\":400,\"description\":\"Bad Request: Message text is empty\"}"
    AsyncState: null
    CancellationPending: false
    CreationOptions: None
    Exception: null
    Id: 80
    Result: "{\"ok\":false,\"error_code\":400,\"description\":\"Bad Request: Message text is empty\"}"
    Status: RanToCompletion
```

### EDIT

I found the issue is with optional fields, if i pass null or empty to them, the telegram api still look for that, and throw errors, if i don't send them at all, it will work. Now how to tell contractResolver, to ignore null fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some other test, and talk to a friend who implement it in another language, i found out that the optional parameters cannot be null nor empty, so i searched to find a way to not send them, well obviously as i didn't used dynamic and created all the model and defined them, i couldn't just simply omit sending of those properties, so after some search, i found a very simple way i couldn't think about...

Here's the answer:
`NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`

The `NullValueHandling` is a Property of `JsonSerializerSettings` class, and i used it like:

```
HttpContent requestContent = new ObjectContent(typeof(SendMessage<object>), newMessage,
new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CustomPropertyNamesContractResolver
        {
            Case = IdentifierCase.UnderscoreSeparator
        },
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    },
SupportedEncodings = {Encoding.UTF8}
});
```